# Scala & Play - Pass parameters to a filter

Tags: scala, playframework, http-headers

I have a filter which should send a token in the result header, which needs to be calculated within the controller.

```
class TokenFilter @Inject()(implicit val mat: Materializer, 
ec: ExecutionContext, token: String) extends Filter{
def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
       (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
  result.withHeaders("token" -> token)
}}}
```

The controller looks like this:

```
def getAll(meta: MetaData): Action[AnyContent] = deadbolt.Restrict(group)(parse.default) { implicit request =>
myService.getAll(meta).map(result => {
  implicit val token: String = getToken
  val list: Seq[Resp] = result._2.map(exp => Mapper(exp))
  Ok(Json.toJson(ListResponse.apply(meta, result._1, list)))
})}
```

It looks like the function which gets the token works fine but the filter cannot access the token.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Please, check if you plugged you filter to rest of your application. See for more details: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaHttpFilters#Using-filters

Comment: Hey Ivan, the filter is connected and produces the result. I just can't seem to get values from the controller to it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In this case if token calculated inside the controller, then `withHeaders` should be invoked inside the controller, not in the filter. Do you need to insert this token only in this controller or in all of them? Or you would like to override token value only in this particular controller?

Comment: Yes I have a lot of controllers so the solution needs to be able to get the token without adding the headers to each call separately. So I guess I need to modify something within the controller so that each call's result would also calculate and add the token. Right?

Comment: Please, provide details, how `getToken` method works in `implicit val token: String = getToken`  construction, because right now `TokenFilter ` accept `token` parameter in construction - I think this is the issue

Comment: The method getToken is located in my parent controller (so all controllers have access to it). the method looks like this: protected def getToken(implicit req: AuthenticatedRequest[Any]): String = {
    req.subject match {
      case userOpt@Some(user: User) => userOpt.flatMap(_ => Some(user.token)).getOrElse("")
      case _                        => ""
    }
  }